# Moving from xy to another point, where am I at time t?

Tags: java, math

How would I write a function to move from point1 to point2 given some time?

For example:

```
Point move(Point point1, Point point2, long timeInMilliseconds, int speedPerSecond)
{
  // basic stuff
  int pointsMoved = speedPerSecond * 1000 / timeInMilliseconds;
  if (point1.x == point2.x && point1.y > point2.y)
    return (new Point(point1.x, Math.min(point2.y, point1.y + pointsMoved)));
  ...
}
```

Yes, that's where my sad math skills end.
How do I move if the movement is not diagonal or vertical? if there's an angle?

BTW, I plan to recalculate the current point based on point1 and point2, I will not be updating point1 nor point2 from the caller, so caller would look like this:

```
Point currentPoint = move(originalPoint, finalPoint, getCurrentTime() - originalTime, 10);
```

The signature of the function doesn't have to be what I mentioned.  It could very well use degrees, but that's going to be another thing to figure out, if I have to use degrees.

Comment: Time to do a little reading up on very basic trigonometry. You'll need to know this stuff later regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the general motion formula:

> p = k⟨p<sub>2</sub> - p<sub>1</sub>⟩ + p<sub>1</sub>

**p<sub>1</sub>** is the initial position. **p<sub>2</sub>** is the final position. **p** is the current location. **k** is a ratio, usually between 0 and 1, that determines how much of the distance to p<sub>2</sub> we've covered.

Your function receives **t<sub>n</sub>**, the current time, and **v**, the speed from the p<sub>1</sub> to p<sub>2</sub>. Therefore we need one additional piece to calculate k: the distance from p<sub>1</sub> to p<sub>2</sub>. t<sub>n</sub> is in time units (*t*), the distance |p<sub>2</sub> - p<sub>1</sub>| is in distance units (*d*), and the speed is in distance per time units (*d* / *t*). k is unitless, so we have to neutralize the units in the three values.

> *d* / (*d* / *t*) / *t*
>   = *d* / *d* · *t* / *t*
>   = 1

and our units are neutralized.

So we have:

> k = |p<sub>2</sub> - p<sub>1</sub>| / v / t<sub>n</sub>

The distance is easily determined via the Pythagorean Theorem, giving us k. From there we decompose the general formula into its components:

> p<sub>x</sub> = k(x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) + x<sub>1</sub>
>   p<sub>y</sub> = k(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>) + y<sub>1</sub>

k, being unitless despite containing elements with components, does not get decomposed.